# Upsert in prisma without ID creates duplicate records (promise error?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, prisma, plumatic-schema

I need to insert records in a PG database from a `json` file with 500k records.

Since the file is huge I'm creating a Read Stream and using `JSONStream.parse` to send `json` objects over to `pipe`.

So far so good. This is not the problem, I'm just providing context.

After parsing the object, I need to insert the information using `prisma` but I cannot insert records if certain field is already in the table. So first thing I think is that I should use an `upsert`.

The problem is that this field is not a unique key of that table, therefore I cannot use it in the `where` clause of the `prisma upsert`.

Then, I did the following:

```
           await prisma.pets
              .findFirst({
                where: { name: nameFromJson },
              })
              .then(async (existing_pet) => {
                if (!existing_pet) {
                  await prisma.pets.create({
                    data: {
                      name: nameFromJson,
                      legs: numberOfLegs,
                      isAlive: isAlive,
                    },
                  })
                }
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                throw new Error(error)
              })
```

My idea is to find the record with the same field first and when that promise is resolved, send the result to another promise where I can check the record and if it does not exist, then just shoot the `create`.

But I keep getting duplicates in the table.

I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong. And of course, what would be the right way to proceed in a scenario like this.